# Error CS5001: exe does not contain a static `Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have all of a sudden started to receive the following error when trying to compile my MonoTouch Project.

> Error CS5001: Program 'MyApp.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point (CS5001) (MyApp)

Below is what my Main.cs looks like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Application
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I can do to fix the issue? Or do I need to create a new solution?

Comment: Which MonoTouch version did you use? Did that message appears if you create new project?

Comment: Im using MonoDevelop V 3.0.4.7 and MonoTouch v 6.0.0

Comment: New projects work fine, it looks like something has got corrupted in my project, just not sure what?

Comment: What is the BuildAction of your Main.cs (right-click the file in MonoDevelop)? It should be set to 'Compile'.

Comment: Thanks Rolf, that was it for some reason it had got changed to Content.

Comment: Hey i have same problem occur in my application and i an new in monoMac so plz tell me what is the solution???

Comment: @Leena Check that the Build Action for your main.cs is set to compile

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could have missed STAThread:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 ...
}
```